# Searching through objects using their names in c# using windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-core

For a university project I was tasked with creating a crossword game in windows forms using c#, I have 25 textboxes laid out in a grid and named with their indexes(e.g. txtCell00, txtCell01).
[Image of the form layout with the textbox names and layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSpGQ.jpg)

To check the guesses I want to loop through all the cells and compare them to an array of the correct answers, but I don't know how to loop through all the cells without having 25 nested if statements. I wanted to know if there was a way to use string manipulation in the actual code
e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    for(int m = 0; m <= 4; m++){
        if(txtCell[i][m].Text == ans[i][m])
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am probably being stupid and there is probably a better alternative so I would greatly appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: So `and` is an 2D array holding the correct strings? If so, whats wrong with your solution?

Comment: ans is a 2d array holding the correct char values for the crossword. I think the problem is that txtCell[I][m] isn't actually an object because there are no text boxes that are called that, my idea was to hopefully have i and m be replaced in the code with the loop integers so the actual condition would read txtCell00.Text but i don't think that is possible.

Comment: OK, in that case simply create a separate object which is 2D array of text cells, assign your text cells to it and use it in your loop as shown above. This should work fine. 
If this is not clear, could you add all your code concerning the text cells and your `ans` array, please?

Comment: This worked great. thanks man I probably never would have thaught of that:)